# Handling a JFileChooser window close?

Tags: java

I have a JFileChooser that is created as shown:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
int choosen = chooser.showOpenDialog(fileSelector.this);

if (choosen == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
  System.out.println("Closed");
}
```

If I close the window with out making a selection I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fileSelector.fileSelector(fileSelector.java:32)
    at createAndControl.main(createAndControl.java:15)
```

I wanted to know what the proper way to handle this was, what action should I call on window closed to avoid this?

TIA

Comment: What line is causing the exception?

Comment: whats on fileselector.java line 32 ? you can refer to the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) on JFileChooser if you like - it has some good code samples.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked. As the other said more code would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's recommended to do it the other way round:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                //This is where a real application would open the file.
                System.out.println("Opening: " + file.getName() + ".\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Open command cancelled by user.\n");
            }
        }
    });
}
```